# Condition for symmetric part of $A$ for $\|x(t)\|$ monotonically decreasing ($\dot{x} = Ax(t)$)

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems, positive-definite

Recall the following discussion:
[When is the symmetric part of a matrix positive definite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634622/when-is-the-symmetric-part-of-a-matrix-positive-definite)

Suppose $\dot{x} = Ax$ is asymptotically stable.

I am no quite understand why the following is the condition for $\|x(t)\|$ monotonically decreasing?

> $A^T+A  \prec 0$, i.e., the symmetric part of $A$ is negative definite

This result is from S. Boyd's lecture p.19:

https://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/lq-lyap.pdf

Can anyone give me a hint to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the positive definite function
$$
V(x)= \|x\|^2=x^Tx=x^T I x.
$$
Its derivative along the trajectories of the system
$$\tag{1}
\dot x=Ax
$$
is equal to
$$
\dot V(x)=\frac{dV(x(t))}{dt}=x^T (A^T I+IA) x=x^T (A^T +A) x.
$$
Since $A^T+A$ is negative definite, the quadratic form $x^T (A^T +A) x$ is negative for any $x\ne 0$, thus, $V(x)$ decreases along every nonzero trajectory of (1).