# Is a matrix $M$ PD iff its symmetric part is PD?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

I have seen it claimed multiple places (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/634622/259085) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2307752/259085)) that a (not necessarily symmetric) matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is PD (i.e., $x^TMx>0$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$) if and only if its symmetric part $\frac{1}{2}(M+M^T)$ is PD.

This is the case if $\frac{1}{2}x^T(M-M^T)x=0$, however I am only able to show this if $M$ is symmetric (in which case it is trivial).

Are the above linked claims true or false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$\langle x, (M+M^{\mathrm{t}}) x\rangle = \langle x, M x\rangle + \langle x, M^{\mathrm{t}} x\rangle = \langle x, M x\rangle + \langle M x, x\rangle = 2\langle x, M x\rangle.$$

Comment: Sorry, why is $\langle x, M x\rangle = \langle M x, x\rangle$? Wouldn't that require $M=M^T$? Or have I completely forgotten bra-ket notation?

Comment: Ah, it is because they are each other's transpose, right? And the inner product is invariant under transposition (as it is a scalar)?